# Adjusting Moodle user group based on web service request

Tags: php, moodle

I have a Moodle installation integrated with LDAP and based on that it makes the authentication. However, when creating a new user, i wanted Moodle to check a webservice, and based on it's response, assign the user to a group.

Any ideas on how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Web services..

https://github.com/patrickpollet/moodlews/blob/master/wspp/mdl_baseserver.class.php

Use this function add_group()..

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to customise the LDAP enrolment plugin to invoke the webservice and do custom actions. Check the **user_signup()** function in **auth/ldap/auth.php**

Comment: what is the method to make a user join a certain group?

Answer (score 0):

The moodle function to add users into a group is groups_add_member($grouporid, $userorid).

This is defined in moodle/group/lib.php.

Hope this will help.